# How to integrate $\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{4y+\frac{1}{4y^2}+2C_1}}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do I integrate $\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{4y+\frac{1}{4y^2}+2C_1}}$, where $C_1$ is an arbitrary constant?
Is this integral really complex (hard to integrate)?

**EDIT:**
This comes from DE:
$dy/dx = \sqrt{4y+\frac{1}{4y^2}+2C_1}$

Maybe there is another way to get the solution in terms of $x$ or $y$?

Comment: I greatly suspect that this is not going to work with the real calculus. If you want to go with complex variables, you would need a definite integral? What are the bounds?

Comment: Damn, I meant "complex" as hard to integrate, sorry. I will clarify more in edit.

Comment: I  don't think this can be evaluated in terms of elementary functions. The trouble is the cubic in the denominator. If it is factored and you complete the square in the quadratic, you get something of the form $\int\frac{2x\,dx}{\sqrt{(x+\alpha)((x+\beta)^2+\gamma)}}$. If it wasn't for the $(x+\alpha)$, this could be evaluated easily with a trig substitution, but with every substitution I tried, that term made things more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y = p - \frac{C_1}{6}$, the integral can be rewritten as

$$\int\frac{ydy}{\sqrt{4y^3 + 2C_1 y^2 + \frac14}}
= \int\frac{\left(p - \frac{C_1}{6}\right) dp}{\sqrt{4p^3 - \frac{C_1^2}{3}p + \left(\frac14 + \frac{C_1^3}{27}\right)}}$$
Let $\wp(z)$ and $\zeta(z)$ be the [Weierstrass elliptic and zeta functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions) associated with
the ODE

$$\wp'(z)^2 = 4\wp^3(z) - g_2\wp(z) - g_3\quad\text{ where }\quad
\begin{cases}
g_2 &= \frac{C_1^2}{3},\\
g_3 &= -\left(\frac14 + \frac{C_1^3}{27}\right)\end{cases}
$$
Using the substitution $p = \wp(z)$, the integral becomes

$$\int \left( \wp(z) - \frac{C_1}{6}\right) \frac{d\wp(z)}{\sqrt{4\wp^3(z) - g_2\wp(z) - g_3}}$$
For small and positive $z$, $\wp(z)$ behaves likes $\frac{1}{z^2}$ and $\wp'(z) < 0$.
The complicated fraction in above integrand is simply $-dz$ and the integral becomes
$$-\int \left( \wp(z) - \frac{C_1}{6}\right) dz = \zeta(z) + \frac{C_1}{6} z + \text{const.}
\;\;\text{with}\;\;z = \wp^{-1}(p) = \wp^{-1}\left(y + \frac{C_1}{6}\right).$$

If you don't like Weierstrass elliptic functions, one should be able to
express the whole thing in terms of 
[Incomplete elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral)
of the first and second kind. However, the derivation will be more messy.